# How to fix Invalid Class Exception

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I have a model named Student. This is a Java RMI program. I declared the Student Serialized Object in client side. I got following error.

```
    SEVERE: null
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.simulator.model.Student; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6650366980271983195, local class serialVersionUID = 6359019065551364622
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:173)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy2.performList(Unknown Source)
    at com.simulator.ui.student.AddNewStudent.<init>(AddNewStudent.java:90)
    at com.simulator.ui.main.Home$3.actionPerformed(Home.java:109)
    at org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.common.AbstractCommandButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractCommandButton.java:614)
    at org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.common.AbstractCommandButton$ActionHandler.actionPerformed(AbstractCommandButton.java:566)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at org.pushingpixels.flamingo.api.common.model.ActionRepeatableButtonModel.setPressed(ActionRepeatableButtonModel.java:123)
    at org.pushingpixels.flamingo.internal.ui.common.BasicCommandButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicCommandButtonListener.java:147)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3255)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

My Student Class is

```
public class Student implements Model, Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 456544542L;
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

Declaration..

```
List<Student> performListStd = stdController.performList();
        for (Student student : performListStd) {
            mpUsers.put(student.getUserName(), student.getStdPass());
        }
```

stdController has MYSQL query for searching.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try change `serialVersionUID` according stacktrace?

Comment: So consider change to `-6650366980271983195`. It should help

Comment: Also make `serialVersionUID` __private__.